# Transformar un Array de Bytes a Imagen - JAVA

Tags: java

como están?. Estoy intentando pasar un pdf a una imagen, el contenido del pdf lo tengo en formato de un array de bytes

```
byte [] contenidoPDF =  vinculacionService.obtenerDocumentoDelRepositorio(doc.getNumero());
```

pero quiero convertirlo en una imagen ya sea jpg, jpeg o png

Comment: Para eso necesitas usar una librería como https://pdfbox.apache.org/, acá en inglés dan algunos detalles de como se usa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189314/convert-a-pdf-file-to-image

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez esto te funcione, usando la clase de `javax.imageio.ImageIO`.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo.

```
byte[] bytesImagen = obtenerBytesDeLaImagen(); // Aquí deberías reemplazar esto con tu propio array de bytes

try (InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesImagen)) {
    BufferedImage imagen = ImageIO.read(inputStream);

    // Aquí puedes hacer lo que quieras con la imagen, como guardarla en un archivo
    File archivoImagen = new File("imagen.jpg");
    ImageIO.write(imagen, "jpg", archivoImagen);
} catch (IOException e) {
    
}
```

Comment: Buenas, Por lo pronto, no me está funcionando, ya que el arreglo de bytes son  de un pdf, y me esta quedando el BufferedImage en Null. Y esa la controversia que estoy teniendo como pasarlos a una Imagen, para luego obtener de nuevo el arreglo de bytes pero esta vez de una imagen, ya que tengo que pasarle a un servicio externo si o si un array de bytes

Comment: Te falta el proceso de conversión a imagen. Ese código solo escribe la imagen una vez que ya la tienes.